# Change default console loglevel during boot up

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, console

I setup a CentOS 6.3 setup, on which the console loglevel is set to 4, and default log level is set to 4.  I know I can change the default console log level using the following steps:

```
cat /proc/sys/kernel/printk

4   4   1   7

echo 5 > /proc/sys/kernel/printk
cat /proc/sys/kernel/printk

5   4   1   7
```

However, upon reboot, the console log level reverts back to the original value.  Do I need to recompile the kernel, or is there a way I can get the changed value to be persistent across reboot.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

> Do I need to recompile the kernel,

No.

> or is there a way I can get the changed value to be persistent across reboot.

Yes.
Use the kernel command line parameter `loglevel`:

```
loglevel=       All Kernel Messages with a loglevel smaller than the
                    console loglevel will be printed to the console. It can
                    also be changed with klogd or other programs. The
                    loglevels are defined as follows:

                    0 (KERN_EMERG)          system is unusable
                    1 (KERN_ALERT)          action must be taken immediately
                    2 (KERN_CRIT)           critical conditions
                    3 (KERN_ERR)            error conditions
                    4 (KERN_WARNING)        warning conditions
                    5 (KERN_NOTICE)         normal but significant condition
                    6 (KERN_INFO)           informational
                    7 (KERN_DEBUG)          debug-level messages
```

The entire list of parameters possible on the kernel command line are in the [`Linux/Documentation/kernel-parameters.txt`](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/admin-guide/kernel-parameters.txt) file in the source tree.

Depending on your bootloader (e.g. Grub or U-Boot), you will have to edit text to add this new parameter to the command line.  Use `cat /proc/cmdline` to view the kernel command line used for the previous boot.

---

**Addendum**

To display everything, the number supplied for the loglevel parameter would have be be greater than KERN_DEBUG.
That is, you would have to specify `loglevel=8`.
Or simply use the `ignore_loglevel` parameter to display all kernel messages.

Comment: This is pretty late but you can also do it at runtime with Alt-SysRq-0 etc.

Comment: Updated documentation link: https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/admin-guide/kernel-parameters.txt

Comment: Note, for debug messages you might also need `CONFIG_DYNAMIC_DEBUG=y`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28936199/why-is-pr-debug-of-the-linux-kernel-not-giving-any-output/49835405#49835405

Comment: Damn I can't find an easy way to do this with docker-buildroot.