# How to permanently change linux printk log level?

Tags: linux, syslog

I have to run the following command every time when the system is rebooted, in order to get boot time log level changed to level 3:

```
cat /proc/sys/kernel/printk
7 4 1 7
echo "7 4 1 3">/proc/sys/kernel/printk
```

My question is: is there any way I can get the boot time log level set to 3 permanently instead of changing it every time after reboot?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Change default console loglevel during boot up](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16390004/change-default-console-loglevel-during-boot-up)

Comment: But I just want to change the boot time log level, not the default log level. How to do this?

Comment: Put this into the boot arguments for the kernel, then use a mechanism like sysctl.conf file to change it back after boot.

Comment: Easiest way is to just change it in GRUB. See [this](https://linuxconfig.org/introduction-to-the-linux-kernel-log-levels) guide

Answer (score 3):

Just append following line to /etc/sysctl.conf file:

`kernel.printk = 7 4 1 3`