# Hide backtrace from printing in the shell

Tags: c, bash, shell, unix, coredump

I have a program, where I am injecting a fault and I am expecting this to cause a segmentation fault. The problem I am facing is that for a fault such as:

```
char *str = malloc(sizeof(char)*10);
free(str+1);
```

I get the following printed in the shell:

```
*** Error in `./tests': free(): invalid pointer: 0x0000000002442574 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x80996)[0x2abd5ff5b996]
./tests[0x401558]
./tests[0x401735]
./tests[0x402211]
./tests[0x402c1b]
./tests[0x4013fd]
./tests[0x4014a2]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf5)[0x2abd5fefcde5]
./tests[0x4011c9]
======= Memory map: ========
00400000-00407000 r-xp 00000000 08:05 13109176                           /home/jay/Desktop/Mutate/Mutate/CMeanQueue-master/tests
00606000-00607000 r--p 00006000 08:05 13109176                           /home/jay/Desktop/Mutate/Mutate/CMeanQueue-master/tests
00607000-00608000 rw-p 00007000 08:05 13109176                           /home/jay/Desktop/Mutate/Mutate/CMeanQueue-master/tests
00608000-0060a000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
02440000-02461000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                                  [heap]
2abd5fcb7000-2abd5fcd8000 r-xp 00000000 08:05 11274438                   /lib64/ld-2.17.so
2abd5fcd8000-2abd5fcdb000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
2abd5fcef000-2abd5fcf2000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
2abd5fed8000-2abd5fed9000 r--p 00021000 08:05 11274438                   /lib64/ld-2.17.so
2abd5fed9000-2abd5fedb000 rw-p 00022000 08:05 11274438                   /lib64/ld-2.17.so
2abd5fedb000-2abd60098000 r-xp 00000000 08:05 6164261                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.17.so
2abd60098000-2abd60298000 ---p 001bd000 08:05 6164261                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.17.so
2abd60298000-2abd6029c000 r--p 001bd000 08:05 6164261                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.17.so
2abd6029c000-2abd6029e000 rw-p 001c1000 08:05 6164261                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.17.so
2abd6029e000-2abd602a3000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
2abd602a3000-2abd602b8000 r-xp 00000000 08:05 6160389                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
2abd602b8000-2abd604b7000 ---p 00015000 08:05 6160389                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
2abd604b7000-2abd604b8000 r--p 00014000 08:05 6160389                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
2abd604b8000-2abd604b9000 rw-p 00015000 08:05 6160389                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
7fffee8c6000-7fffee8e7000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack]
7fffee993000-7fffee995000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                          [vdso]
ffffffffff600000-ffffffffff601000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                  [vsyscall]
```

Now, what I am looking to do is hide this from the display, since I am making a fault injection tool, I am aware of this happening and do not want such an output to ruin the GUI for the user. I have tried to redirect the stderror to file 2) change unlimit to 0 and nothing works.

NOTE:: I am injecting this problem into a code myself, hence please do not suggest to fix the error. My aim is to hide this from printing on the shell.

Comment: Is running e.g. `./tests 2>> /dev/null` an option, or does it produce other messages on stderr that you actually do want to see? If you can't just ignore stderr, then `libc` may have some environment variables you can set before running your program that affect what messages are displayed, but I can't tell you what they are off the top of my head...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved for the above example using:

```
#export MALLOC_CHECK_=0
```

http://kb.parallels.com/en/4611

Comment: Hi. You should probably accept this answer by now (I know you could not do so immediately when writing the answer since there is a 2 day delay before it is allowed).

Comment: No need to be sorry :)

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your kernel log level to limit what it prints.

something like:

```
bash$ echo "0 0 0 0" > /proc/sys/kernel/printk
```

Great write up here: [Change default console loglevel during boot up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16390004/change-default-console-loglevel-during-boot-up)

Comment: I don't think those messages are coming from the kernel.... They're coming from `libc`...

Comment: Does not seem to work.., also these messages do not print to the console when using OSX..

Comment: Solved it using http://kb.parallels.com/en/4611, not sure what the limitations are though