# Using printk to print data on Linux terminal

Tags: c, linux, linux-device-driver

I currently started learning the **Linux Device driver** programming in Linux. where I found this small piece of code printing hello world using `printk()` function.

```
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/init.h>

MODULE_LICENSE("Dual BSD/GPL");

static int hello_init(void)
{
        printk(KERN_ALERT "Hello World!!!\n");
        return 0;
}

static void hello_exit(void)
{
        printk(KERN_ALERT "Goodbye Hello World!!!\n");
}

module_init(hello_init);
module_exit(hello_exit);
```

After compiling code using `make` command and load driver using `insmod` command. I'm not getting the **"Hello world"** printed on screen instead its printing only on the log file `/var/log/kern.log`. But I want `printk` to print on my ubuntu terminal. I'm using ubuntu(14.04). Is it possible?

Comment: With some trick it's possible, but you perhaps do not need it.

Comment: The output would appear on the *system console*.  For embedded systems and SBCs, the console is typically a specific serial port.  The kernel parameter `console=...` is used to designate the device(s) with optional attributes.  Ubuntu distros typically do not define a console in the command line.

Comment: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/KernelDebuggingTricks

Answer (score 3):

It isn't possible to redirect kernel logs and massages to gnome-terminal and there you have to use `dmesg`.
But in a virtual terminal(open one with `ctrl+F1-F6`) you can redirect them to standard output.
First determine tty number by entering `tty` command in virtual terminal.The output may be **/dev/tty(1-6)**.
Compile and run this code with the argument you specified.

```
/*
* setconsole.c -- choose a console to receive kernel messages
*
* Copyright (C) 1998,2000,2001 Alessandro Rubini
* 
*   This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify
*   it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
*   the Free Software Foundation; either version 2 of the License, or
*   (at your option) any later version.
*
*   This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
*   but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
*   MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
*   GNU General Public License for more details.
*
*   You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
*   along with this program; if not, write to the Free Software
*   Foundation, Inc., 59 Temple Place, Suite 330, Boston, MA 02111-1307, USA.
*/

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char bytes[2] = {11,0}; /* 11 is the TIOCLINUX cmd number */
    if (argc==2) bytes[1] = atoi(argv[1]); /* the chosen console */
    else {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s: need a single arg\n",argv[0]); exit(1);
    }
    if (ioctl(STDIN_FILENO, TIOCLINUX, bytes)<0) {    /* use stdin */
        fprintf(stderr,"%s: ioctl(stdin, TIOCLINUX): %s\n",
            argv[0], strerror(errno));
        exit(1);
    }
    exit(0);
}
```

For example if your output for `tty` command was **/dev/tty1**then type this two command:

```
gcc setconsole.c -o setconsole
sudo ./setconsole 1
```

This will set your tty to receive kernel messages.
Then compile and run this code.

```
/*
 * setlevel.c -- choose a console_loglevel for the kernel
 *
 * Copyright (C) 1998,2000,2001 Alessandro Rubini
 * 
 *   This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify
 *   it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
 *   the Free Software Foundation; either version 2 of the License, or
 *   (at your option) any later version.
 *
 *   This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
 *   but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
 *   MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
 *   GNU General Public License for more details.
 *
 *   You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
 *   along with this program; if not, write to the Free Software
 *   Foundation, Inc., 59 Temple Place, Suite 330, Boston, MA 02111-1307, USA.
 */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/klog.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int level;

    if (argc==2) {
    level = atoi(argv[1]); /* the chosen console */
    } else {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s: need a single arg\n",argv[0]); exit(1);
    }
    if (klogctl(8,NULL,level) < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr,"%s: syslog(setlevel): %s\n",
                argv[0],strerror(errno));
        exit(1);
    }
    exit(0);
}
```

There are 8 level of kernel messages as you specify in your code **KERN_ALERT** is one of them.To make console receive all of them you should run above code with 8 as arguement.
`gcc setlevel.c -o setlevel`
`sudo ./setlevel 8`

Now you can insert your module to kernel and see kernel logs in console.
By the way these codes are from ldd3 examples.

Comment: what should we pass to setconsole when tty command shows /dev/pts/2

Answer (score 0):

`printk` prints to the kernel log. There is no "screen" as far as the kernel is concerned. If you want to see the output of `printk` in real time, you can open a terminal and type the following `dmesg -w`. Note that the `-w` flag is only supported by recent versions of `dmesg` (which is provided by the `util-linux` package).

Comment: *"There is no "screen" as far as the kernel is concerned"* -- Umm, what about the (system) console (which can be designated by a parameter in the kernel command line)?

Comment: You can ask the kernel to output all messages from the kernel log to the main console with `dmesg -n9`, or you can use a smaller value to select only some messages.

Comment: *"You can ask the kernel to output all messages from the kernel log to the main console ..."* -- No, you do not have to *"ask"* for messages on the system console.   See the link above about kernel debugging and  [this question regarding the console log-level](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16390004/change-default-console-loglevel-during-boot-up).  Perhaps you have only used Linux with a GUI front-end?

Comment: Does it look like that I have "_only used Linux with a GUI front-end_"? Read the OP's question and my answer again. It is clear that the OP had the expectation that if they run `modprobe`/`insmod` they would see the `printk` message in the terminal they typed `modprobe` from (the "_screen_"). I was trying to explain that this won't work in a way the OP would understand.