# How to stop kernel messages being printed to console with getty service killed

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel, embedded-linux

I have an embedded Linux system, with `/proc/cmdline` containing `console=<uart device>` and `earlycon=<uart device>`. Shortly after each boot, a getty service will turn `<uart device>` into an interactive console. If I disable the getty service, I would like the console to stop printing messages once everything is initialized. However, I still see kernel messages being printed indfinitely when the getty service disabled. **What is printing these kernel messages (is it a service, a kernel cmdline option, etc)? How do I stop kernel messages from being printed to console indefinitely, without recompiling the kernel? Is there a service I can kill to stop the kernel messages?**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change default console loglevel during boot up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16390004/change-default-console-loglevel-during-boot-up)

Comment: Or change the `console=<uart device>` command line parameter to some other device. "*a getty service will turn <uart device> into an interactive console*" -- You're (incorrectly) conflating "*console*" and "login terminal".

Comment: `dmesg -n 1` will prevent all messages except emergency (panic) messages going to the console.

Comment: In util-linux v2.20 onwards' `dmesg`, `dmesg -D` will disable printing of the messages to the console completely, but that is not currently supported by busybox's `dmesg`.

Comment: Do you have `CONFIG_VT_HW_CONSOLE_BINDING` enabled in your kernel config?